# Uninterruptible thread section in Windows API

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm writing multithreaded application in Windows environment.
Worker loops are terminated by TerminateThread.
I wonder how can I implement code that can not be interrupted to avoid data loss / memory problems :
For example (pseudo code)

```
while(true)
{
#NONINTERRUPTIBLE REGION

do something

#END OF NONINTERRUPTIBLE REGION
#THREAD WILL BE INTERRUPTED THERE (even if call was made earlier)
}
```

I can't find any function in Windows API that can help to do this.
Can somebody give me advice how to do this (boost libraries has this fucntion).

Comment: Your program is already broken. TerminateThread should not be called. You are reaping the just desserts of using that function. It's down to your erroneous use of that function that makes you ask this question. The only viable solution is to fix your broken design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in User mode to block the thread being terminated.

This means that any objects such as `CriticalSection`s and class internals can be  left in an undefined state.

Use signals (variables, Events) to signal threads, with a `WaitForSingleObject` to find when the thread has actually gone.

From the [MSDN TerminateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx), 
`TerminateThread` is dangerous, breaking kernel 32 state, dll state and critical sections.

Obviously pointers in your code could also be broken.

The function `TerminateThread` is a last resort - probably pre-program termination for trying to avoid some worse behavior.

### Update 1

```
volatile int threadOK; // set to false when thread should complete

Threadfunction() 
{
  while( threadOK )
  {
   #NONINTERRUPTIBLE REGION

   do something

   #END OF NONINTERRUPTIBLE REGION
   #THREAD WILL BE INTERRUPTED THERE (even if call was made earlier)
  }
}
```

Comment: `volatile` isn't enough. While this prevents the compiler from optimizing out read operations, you'll also have to make read-modify-write operations atomic (e.g. by using `std::atomic`).

Comment: @IInspectable Nothing is enough in the face of `TerminateThread`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the answer is saying to use a `volatile` *instead* of `TerminateThread`, not in addition to it.

Comment: @Harry OK, I understand now

Comment: I avoided `std::atomic` because a) it didn't say `C++11` and b) it didn't need it.  From all the research I have done, a change from a `volatile int` will a) not tear, and b) reach all threads, so was sufficient.  It becomes undefined behavior, only where other variables are taken into account.  The use of `std::atomic` causes slow down on the CPU, which may not be helpful, nor needed.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true.  See [the description of volatile in the VS2015 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx).  If you are in ISO mode, it explicitly says that you must not use `volatile` for cross-thread communication.  (I can't say that I understand why!)  If you're using `/volatile:ms` you're OK.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a poor design. I would do the other way around, let the threads check some flag and terminate. If you still need to be able to kill "runaway" threads that aren't behaving, then do a "fair warning" system, where each thread has a flag to look at, and if it's set, terminate. Then monitor such threads, and if they haven't terminated themselves after X amount of time, do the terminate.

Make sure you use `std::atomic` to ensure that the flag is properly written and read across threads.